# Convergence of $\sum_n \frac{n!}{n^n}$

Tags: convergence-divergence

I'm working on a problem sheet and it ask to discuss the convergence of 
$$\sum \frac{n!}{{n}^{n}}$$
By D'Lembert's ratio test,
$$\lim_{n->\infty}\frac{{a}_{n+1}}{{a}_{n}} = 1$$
and so, is inconclusive.

Using Cauchy's root test,

$$\lim_{n->\infty}({\frac{n!}{{n}^{n}}})^\frac{1}{n}=1$$

What are my alternatives?

Should I take the integral of the term of the series above? Would integrating factorial works?

Comment: did you think about the comparison test ?

Comment: [series test srtagies](https://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftutorial.math.lamar.edu%2FClasses%2FCalcII%2FSeriesStrategy.aspx&ei=BAAQVd_qKInk8gWYlICoDA&usg=AFQjCNH984VVZZvjEJe9sxJqwPyAGlRgjQ)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually the ratio test turns out to be conclusive :

$$\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{{a}_{n+1}}{{a}_{n}} &=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}} \cdot \dfrac{n^n}{n!} \\~\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n+1}{(n+1)^{n+1}} \cdot \dfrac{n^n}{1} \\~\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\dfrac{n}{n+1}\right)^n\\~\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\dfrac{\color{blue}{n+1}-1}{n+1}\right)^n\\~\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\color{blue}{1}+\dfrac{-1}{n+1}\right)^n\\~\\&=e^{-1}~~\color{Red}{\star} \\~\\&\lt 1\end{align}$$

$\color{red}{\star}$ : please see [$e^x$ limit definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_exponential_function)

Comment: Looks like the root test also works.

Comment: Looks like it does. I see where I went wrong although I do not see how the argument follows from the fourth line to the fifth.

Comment: Ahh skipped few lines in between... I have updated, please check now

Comment: Sorry it was a typo. I was able to follow what you've just edited. I meant to say I was not able to follow the 5th to the 6th line.

Comment: Ohk.. got you :) I'll add a reference to that limit..

Comment: Incase if that $n+1$ in the denominator is throwing you off $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\color{blue}{1}+\dfrac{-1}{n+1}\right)^n = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\color{blue}{1}+\dfrac{-1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\left(\color{blue}{1}+\dfrac{-1}{n+1}\right) \\~\\=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\color{blue}{1}+\dfrac{-1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}~\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\color{blue}{1}+\dfrac{-1}{n+1}\right) =e^{-1}\cdot 1  $$

Comment: Thanks but I was able to recognize that trick much like x = sqrt[x^(2)] "!" =P

Answer (score 5):

$$\frac{n!}{n^n}=\frac{1}{n}\frac{2}{n}\cdots\frac{n-1}{n}\frac{n}{n}<\frac2{n^2}$$

Comment: I will try this too.

Comment: Ah yes it converges since if Sum[2/(n^(2)] from n=1 to infinity  converges then by the direct comparison test, a_n converges

Comment: How do you see that this inequality holds?

Comment: @user161825: In the middle term there, you have $\frac 1n\frac 2n$ multiplied several times by something less than $1$. Therefore, $\frac 1n\frac 2n=\frac 2{n^2}$ is greater.

Comment: I also don't think that's instantly immediate for which n this works, or why exactly $n^2$ pops up. It calls for a proof by induction.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: $\dfrac{n!}{n^n} < \dfrac{2}{n^2}$.